# How can I set the value of a textbox through PHP?

Tags: php

So I have this empty textboxes in a registrationg page. The user enters some data, hits continue and then there's a confirmation page. If the data is incorrect, the user hits go back to go correct whatever was wrong. However, when he goes back, all the textboxes are empty. So the first thing that comes to my mind is to store the user data in a Session (I have a User class that holds all this data so I store the class in the session). When the user goes back I am able to retrieve the data.

I do something like this:

```
if($_SESSION['UserInfo'])
{
    $user = $_SESSION['UserInfo'];

    $firstName = $user->FirstName;
    $lastName = $user->LastName;
}
```

How would I put these variables in a textbox?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To set the value, you can just echo out the content inside the `value` attribute:

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?php echo htmlentities($firstName); ?>" />
<input type="text" name="lastname" value="<?php echo htmlentities($lastName); ?>" />
```

Comment: +1 only answer so far to get the escaping right; shame on the others. Although `htmlspecialchars()` is just as effective, and `ENT_QUOTES` is generally prefaerable, though it doesn't matter here.

Comment: They did not ask how to escape it... they asked how to put it into the text box. Besides... what do you think that "Of course you will want to escape it but..." means?

Comment: @Sean: Well with that mindset, if you teach someone how to fire a gun... are you going to leave out the part about safety?

Comment: @brianreavis: No... I would not. I was actually more annoyed that I and a couple of others were down voted because we left something out that was not within the scope of the question.

Comment: @Sean: Ahh gotcha... yeah, definitely not worth a down vote. I'm with you on that.

Answer (score 4):

Of course you will want to escape it but...

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $firstName ?>" />
```

or if the form is posted, it would be easier to do:

```
<input type="text" name="firstName" value="<?php echo $_POST['firstName'] ?>" />
```

fine... even though it was out of the scope of the question here is the escaped version:

```
<input type="text" name="firstName" value="<?php echo htmlentities($_POST['firstName']) ?>" />
```

Comment: You could incorporate an example of `htmlentities()`

Comment: Seriously? Voted down because of that?

Comment: Thanks! That is what I did for all of the rest of the down voted answers

Answer (score 3):

smth like

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $first_name;?>">
```

Don't forget to escape with htmlentities() or smth similar. If you don't know why - google XSS.

Comment: You could incorporate an example of `htmlentities()`

Comment: Seriously? Voted down because of that?