# textbox = php variable?

Tags: php, variables, textbox

I want to get value from php variable to review it in textbox

what I have to write in "value":

```
<input type="text" name="name3" size="25" maxlength="50" value=""> name:
```

Comment: I'll give my upvote to the first person thinking of doing a `htmlspecialchars()` on the output. :)

Comment: I'd just like to point out that 16 seconds isn't enough time to read that comment and answer the question ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I set the value of a textbox through PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484816/how-can-i-set-the-value-of-a-textbox-through-php)

Comment: To use php you first need to learn php.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" 
       name="name3" 
       size="25" 
       maxlength="50" 
       value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($variable); ?>">
```

Comment: Sorry for the late comment, but I just want to ask if htmlspecialchars will also work if you do the same in the textbox name. '<input type="text" name=<?php echo htmlspecialchars($str); ?> value="hello">' , for example. Thanks.

Comment: Only for some value of work that doesn't protect against XSS. You need to quote the attribute values. `name="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($str); ?>"` would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="name3" size="25" maxlength="50" value="<?php echo $variable; ?>">
```