# How to enter value on textbox using php and get it by javascript

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I want to be able to have a text box on a page where php writes into and javascript read from

I saw this solution
[How can I set the value of a textbox through PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484816/how-can-i-set-the-value-of-a-textbox-through-php)

use it and I manage to write the value on the textbox using this command

```
<input type=\"text\" name=\"txtFromPHP\" value=\"" .$row['id'] . "\">
```

but when I access the textbox usng this

```
var str = document.getElementById('txtFromPHP').value;
```

I get error

```
document.getElementById("txtFromPHP") is null
```

Just maybe it's relevant, my html page where textbox is placed is a modified version of Ajax Database example found at http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_ajax_database.asp

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the element ID as follows

```
<input type=\"text\" id=\"txtFromPHP\" name=\"txtFromPHP\" value=\"" .$row['id'] . "\">
```

In your example you only set the name of the element `txtFromPHP` and did not set an ID

Answer (score 1):

change the "name" to "id" or have them both:

```
<input type=\"text\" id=\"txtFromPHP\" value=\"" .$row['id'] . "\">
```